# Typescript Interface Definition dynamic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am trying to define an interface for the following data:

```
result =
{
   "data1" : [ { "type1" : 30 }, { "type2" :40 } ],
   "data1" : [ { "abc" : 40 }, { "def" 940 } ],
   "data3" : []
}
```

here the keys and values inside `result` object are dynamic. Even the values inside array of objects are dynamic but it will be of format `string: number` or that array can be empty just as in `data3`.

I tried using `[x:any]: any`, but looks like it will remove the significance of rest of the types defined in interface as it will match eveything.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can define dynamic key interface as follows:

```
interface Result {
  [key: string]: {
    [childKey: string]: number;
  }[];
}
```

Comment: but whats childkey and key?

Comment: It's just a variable name that suggests typescript that the key is dynamic. You can have any name you want. Also since JavaScript object keys are strings, you specify it as string.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar you can do -->

You don't need to use an indexer (since it a bit less typesafe). You have two options :

```
interface EnumServiceItem {
   id: int; label: string; key: any
}

interface EnumServiceItems extends Array<EnumServiceItem>{}


// Option A 
var result: EnumServiceItem[] = [
 { id: 0, label: 'CId', key: 'contentId' },
 { id: 1, label: 'Modified By', key: 'modifiedBy' },
 { id: 2, label: 'Modified Date', key: 'modified' },
 { id: 3, label: 'Status', key: 'contentStatusId' },
 { id: 4, label: 'Status > Type', key: ['contentStatusId', 'contentTypeId'] },
 { id: 5, label: 'Title', key: 'title' },
 { id: 6, label: 'Type', key: 'contentTypeId' },
 { id: 7, label: 'Type > Status', key: ['contentTypeId', 'contentStatusId'] }
];


// Option B
var result: EnumServiceItems = [
 { id: 0, label: 'CId', key: 'contentId' },
 { id: 1, label: 'Modified By', key: 'modifiedBy' },
 { id: 2, label: 'Modified Date', key: 'modified' },
 { id: 3, label: 'Status', key: 'contentStatusId' },
 { id: 4, label: 'Status > Type', key: ['contentStatusId', 'contentTypeId'] },
 { id: 5, label: 'Title', key: 'title' },
 { id: 6, label: 'Type', key: 'contentTypeId' },
 { id: 7, label: 'Type > Status', key: ['contentTypeId', 'contentStatusId'] }
 ]
```

Personally I recommend Option A (simpler migration when you are using classes not interfaces).